# How can I test for electrical current through bare wires without a meter?

Tags: home, substitute-tool, electricity

Similar to [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/103/check-for-electricity-in-a-socket-without-tools), but I'm asking specifically about bare wires, with no socket. I don't want to flip a breaker switch, or blow a fuse.

**How can I test for a current in the cable(s) without a dedicated meter?**

Comment: What kind of current are you expecting? If you don't know, you really just shouldn't be doing this without proper equipment.

Comment: @TomMedley 125 volts. 20 amps.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this.

Comment: @J.Musser There are [electro screwdrivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_light#mediaviewer/File:Phasenpruefer_01-l_KMJ.jpg) for that situation. A thing that you should carry with you if you attempt to work on electricity. Also taking out the fuse manually makes sure that there is no current on the wires, which is easier then testing.

Comment: You should include the situation in which the wires are found. Is it in your home? Outside? Do you have control over the breaker?

Comment: It might help to know why you want to do this. Do you actually want to know if the wire is "hot", i.e., has voltage on it? Or do you want to know if current is flowing? It can be hot (and dangerous if the voltage is high enough) and yet have no current flowing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any hack is inherently unsafe. Go to the store and get the proper equipment.

Comment: @Jon This question was kinda meant as a test question in the early days of the site. It has already been closed, reopened, closed again, reopened,  Deleted by Shog, undeleted, etc. Personally, I'd like to simply close/lock/delete it.

Comment: @J.Musser cant you delete as the OP?

Comment: @Jon I can, and also because I'm a mod now. My main reason for not wanting that is because of the upvotes on the answers it got.

Comment: @Jim It's a multi purpose voltage tester of some brand, which (imo) is quite easy to understand. They're quite common, and anyone could buy one. I was surprised I didn't get it as an answer earlier.  Which part of the answer were you struggling to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use this.

> [image: tester]
>
> [image source](http://www.cableorganizer.com/images/outlet/product/efilliate-P24900a.jpg)

It glows when current is present. That way you won't have to touch the wire.

However, as stated by everybody, *be careful*.

Comment: What is *the name* of this device?

Comment: *Electric tester* . ( as they call it in India, Asia).

Comment: A clamp meter would work as well. It clamps around the wire without touching it and shows any current through it. (However it will not show voltage potential, which is just as dangerous)

Answer (score 7):

***Theoretically***, you could take a lightbulb (or nightlight, phone charger, etc.) and touch the wires to the bulb base or plug.

## HOWEVER: DO NOT ATTEMPT

This would be ***EXTREMELY*** dangerous: you could die from the electrical shock. Even experienced electricians and crazy people don't do such a thing!

---

#### In conclusion

This is one reason there are breaker switches: so you can *safely* work on wiring, etc. without dying.

To answer your original question with a *good* and *safe* idea: *Don't do it!* Use the proper equipment.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what exactly the danger is and why it's so dangerous.

Comment: @starsplusplus I added `: you could die from the electrical shock`

Comment: Excuse my electrical ignorance, but how do you get electrocuted if you're holding the bulb and not touching the wire?

Comment: Why do you ask that? The dangerous part is handling the live, uninsulated wires.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realised you were suggesting touching the wires! I assumed you were suggesting holding the bulb and touching it to the wires (which could also be dangerous for all I know).

Comment: Rubber gloves do negate most of the danger though. Insulated tools help if you don't have gloves. However, given the sketchy question, this answer is probably spot on.

Comment: This answer is technically WRONG when it comes to determining if there is current flowing through the wires. All it will do is tell you there is current flowing *through the light bulb AFTER you connect the lightbulb*. It also is not clear from the answer how the lightbulb is expected to be connected.

Comment: @Jim "touch the wires to the bulb base"

Comment: If I gave my wife those instructions, I could be indicted for attempted murder. :) The rest of your answer is still technically wrong, or else the question is not written clearly, and you're answering what you think the OP means rather than what was asked. See my comment to the OPs question.